# Android record only voice in "karaoke" app

Tags: java, android, audio-recording, voice-recording

**What I have**

I have a basic "karaoke" app that shows some text, plays music and lets the user to record his "song" to share it with friends.

**Problem**

We use the same device (tablet/phone) to record voice and play background music, so the final quality of the record is very poor.

**What I want**

I have high quality sources of music that plays on background so want to use them instead of noisy one from the record output.
So I see two options here:

1. Can I somehow extract the voice from the karaoke record and mix it
   with my high quality music sources?
2. Can I somehow apply inverted
   music source to remove background music from the karaoke record?

Comment: Might sound like a joke, but you can use headphones. The music is no longer a problem.

Comment: @Korcholis 
It can be a good option but totally broke whole "karaoke" party idea) 
Anyway thank you!

Comment: if you check the famous app like simuly, even they don't have any thing like this(Splitting music and voice). So i think till now there is no android supported library available for this. May in future it will arrive.

Comment: I've never tried it for a situation this demanding, but [AcousticEchoCanceler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AcousticEchoCanceler) is what you're looking for.

Comment: something i tried recently, might help https://github.com/unicorncoderforever/AndroidKaraoke